# How to use one function multiple times in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create quantity section with reactjs but this is working only for one section. How can I make it multiple.

When I'm click on up arrow then count is increasing same in all the {qty}. but I need when I'll click on up arrow then it should be count as per the products.

Problem:- count is coming same:
[image]

Solution:- count should not same it should be like given below:
[image]

My Code:-

```js
const BuyProducts = () => {
  const title = 'Buy Products New';
  const classes = productsStyles();

  const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);

  const quantityMinus = () => {
    if (!qty == 0) {
      setQty(qty - 1);
    }
  };
  const quantityPlus = () => {
    setQty(qty + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div onClick={quantityPlus} className="qty-action">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleUp} />
        </div>
        <div>{qty}</div>
        <div onClick={quantityMinus} className="qty-action">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div onClick={quantityPlus} className="qty-action">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleUp} />
        </div>
        <div>{qty}</div>
        <div onClick={quantityMinus} className="qty-action">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: This needs some more clarity. I'm having trouble understanding the issue. What exactly is the problem and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: actually there is multiple product box div inside it I define quantity section where i'm using useState but when I'm increasing it then all the product's quantity increasing it should be update as per the product.

Comment: If you need to update different values for different products than you need to manage additional state. Either with seperate `useState` hooks, or simply turn your existing state into an object that can have different values (quantities) for different keys (products).

Comment: I update my question with screenshot  It will be more clear to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create some form of a data structure to manage multiple quantities. Since you're only using one `qty` variable right now, only one thing will ever change.

Let's say you have a simple `CartItem` interface to represent some shopping cart item that has quantity + a name or id of the item being purchased.

(It could look something like this if you were using typescript.)

```
interface CartItem {
  name: string;
  quantity: number;
}
```

Then in React, you'd want to store a collection of these `CartItem`s in your state somewhere so you can track how many objects you need to render. You could use an object, set, or just a simple array depending on your use case. Let's use an array.

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([{name: 'apple', quantity: 0}, {name: 'orange', quantity: 1}]); // initial data as an example
```

Next, your quantityUp/down functions need to be a little bit more generic so that they can receive a `CartItem` object as an argument and you can accordingly use that to figure out which cart item to update.

```
const changeQuantity = useCallback((item, quantityChange) => {
  // Find the item to update
  const oldCartItems = [...cartItems]; 
  const itemIndex = oldCartItems.findIndex((oldItem) => oldItem.name === item.name);

  // Change the quantity
  oldCartItems[itemIndex].quantity += quantityChange;

  // Put it back in state
  setCartItems(oldCartItems);
}, [cartItems]);
```

Finally, in your rendering/JSX, you don't need to keep writing the same JSX over and over again. You can map through the `cartItems` state.

```
return (
    <div>
      {cartItems.map((cartItem) => 
      <div>
        <div onClick={() => changeQuantity(cartItem, 1)} className="qty-action">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleUp} />
        </div>
        <div>{cartItem.quantity}</div>
        <div onClick={() => changeQuantity(cartItem, -1)} className="qty-action">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} />
        </div>
      </div>
}
    </div>
);
```